# Python :: catching exceptions in order to traverse a list

Tags: python, exception

Here's the code, part of a solution to [problem 11 in Euler Project](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=11):

```
sum_d = 0
j = 0
while j < 20:
    i = 0
    while i < 20:
        try:
            sum_d = grid[j][i] * grid[j+1][i+1] * grid[j+2][i+2] * grid[j+3][i+3]
            if sum_d > result:
                result = sum_d
        except IndexError:
            pass
        i += 1
    j += 1
```

My question is whether catching those exceptions is considered a code smell? I can see that it will be tougher to debug such code (say, I accidentally looped over 19 items instead of 20, it will be harder to trace) but it is much more elegant then, say, coding `i < (GRID_WIDTH - NUM_ITEMS_IN_PRODUCT)`
in the loop check.

P.S. I already solved the problem, I'm talking about the style of code

Comment: you should use numpy to solve that one. It has a diag function and can be used in 4x4 blocks (that's how i remember i solved it).

Comment: possible duplicate of [which style is preferred?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114540/which-style-is-preferred)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spoiler: Here's part of my solution for [problem 11](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=11).

```
for x in range(0,16):
    for y in range(0,16):
        prod = p[y][x] * p[y+1][x+1] * p[y+2][x+2] * p[y+3][x+3]
        m = max(m, prod)
```

Using exceptions instead of basic control structures is imho always a bad idea. This time you can get away with looping through the numbers 0..15!

Also, if you muliply stuff you get a [*product*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_%28mathematics%29), not a [*sum*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation). ;)

Comment: +1 for smart, I'd give another +1 for Pythonic use of range rather than explicit loop counters.

Comment: After seeing this I went back to look at my solution to p11 and found this comment to myself: `# this is wrong; horizontal and vertical rows in the corners don't get tested`. For some reason that made me laugh.

Comment: +1, but it will be faster (and more pythonic) as: max((p[y][x] * p[y+1][x+1] * p[y+2][x+2] * p[y+3][x+3] for x in range(16) for y in range(16))). Using the generator comprehension instead of the list comprehension is a good idea since we only want the maximal value

Comment: I think "always a bad idea" is a bit strong. I'd say "usually" rather than "always". Sometimes you really do have exceptional situations. Although you can always rewrite exception-throwing code so that it returns exceptional values instead, the cost in terms of clarity and concision is sometimes too much to pay.

Answer (score 1):

You could at least make it

```
except IndexError:
    break
```

Anyway, yes I believe this is a code smell, and no it is not clearer than

```
for i in range(gridsize - num_items_in_product):
```